# Ansible Gathering Facts not working?

Tags: ansible

Everytime I run a playbook, ansible will install the packages again and again, even thought it is installed, so how does it work actually?

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts  site.yml
GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [192.168.0.2]

TASK: [Install via apt] *************************************** 
changed: [192.168.0.2] => (item=build-essential,python-dev,python-software-properties,python-setuptools)
```

My cookbook (Tasks):

```
 name: Install via apt
  action: apt pkg=$item
  with_items:
    - build-essential
    - python-dev
    - python-software-properties
```

Comment: Please add the relevant portions of the playbook.

Comment: Can you isolate the issue outside Ansible? What happens when you apt-get install those packages?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error with this playbook:

```
- hosts: 10.0.0.2
  sudo: yes

  tasks:

    - name: Install via apt
      action: apt pkg=$item
      with_items:
         - build-essential
         - python-dev
         - python-software-properties
```

As expected, consecutive executions of the playbook are [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning):

```
$ ansible-playbook pkg.playbook -K
sudo password:

PLAY [10.0.0.2] *********************

GATHERING FACTS *********************
ok: [10.0.0.2]

TASK: [Install via apt] *********************
ok: [10.0.0.2] => (item=build-essential,python-dev,python-software-properties)

PLAY RECAP *********************
10.0.0.2                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```